# How would the magnetic field of a curved ring magnet look like?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I am trying to wrap my head around the concept of how a magnetic field of a ring magnet would change if said ring was curved to a certain degree? Below is a picture of the flux lines of a normal ring magnet:

[image]

This picture could best describe the idea of the magnet in question. How would the magnetic flux lines differ from the picture above?

[image]

If any can please point me to some resources that cover this or provide a detailed conceptual and mathematical explanation, I would greatly appreciate it!

Thank you.

Comment: I am trying to understand something here. The field diagram you show suggests you have a current flowing through your ring (as opposed to having a permanent magnet). Is that what you intended? Please clarify.

Comment: Whether or not a current runs through this shape, it will still display the flux lines as shown. Permanent  magnet also has current associated with it, but at the quantum level.